# Professional approach to design billing block in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, posters

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0350ogNO6CE) video, Adobe expert Deke McClelland talks about designing [**Billing Blocks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billing_(filmmaking)) for film posters with the use of **Warichu** settings in **Adobe Illustrator**. It works well but sometimes there are issues like this:

[image]

- Do **professional movie poster designers** follow this method?
- **How to design billing block in Adobe Photoshop** without copying from Illustrator?

Comment: Could you describe the method you are having issues with? And what issues you are having?

Comment: Please see the screenshot I attached in the question. "Cinematography" should be in one line. But with Warichu it's getting split.

Comment: Warichu is supposed to be used in Japanese Kanji, set vertically; it benefits from the "words" being one character each. In English, with a 14-char word followed by a 2-char word, you are going to struggle.

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I posted this question here.

Comment: So, your choices are... hyphenate, set one word per line, or live with it. It's a 'no fix' situation. For warichu, the 'rules' are being followed, odd number of chars, the higher number goes on the first line. [Spaces are also counted]

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm looking for the professional way to do design the billing block.

Comment: The professional way isn't to use this method. It makes for a fun tutorial to put on Youtube, but that's about it. Too much work to get everything setup sitting right. The typesetting on these posters is usually done in InDesign or Quark(?) with stylesheets and text boxes. Or Illustrator, it's the designers' preference.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use that feature. It's far too complicated.

To create the layout, you could simply make one group of two text boxes. Setting up the correct size fonts and changing the leading are as complicated as it needs to get. Then you could simply <kbd>Alt</kbd>+drag then hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to duplicate the group, and edit the text in the duplicate. Then nudge it into position with the arrow keys.

For the "CINEMATOGRAPY" title, you could split it into two words with "BY" on the second line.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes, there isn't a "faster way". Sometimes, you just gotta do the work!

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution to this, although slightly hacky, is to add garbage text at the end of the first line, and then make it transparent. For example, given the following issue:

[image]

You can just add some text after "Written", without a space in between:

[image]

...until the text wraps at the correct position, here, it reads as "Writtener by". Then, it's just a matter of making the "er" transparent (just select it, and set the fill to `[none]`

[image]

I have to say, I don't know if using the Warichu settings is the "professional" way of doing things, but I definitely finds it's the easiest. It's a tiny bit more effort to get things looking how you want them to in the first place, but you then have a lot more flexibility and room to do minor changes (typo on an actor's name, missing credit, etc...), as you don't need to worry about the wrapping and spacing between the credits.